# Interaction plot with betareg in R and two continuous variables

Tags: r, betareg

I am looking for a function in R, that will take the output from the betareg regression, and plot an interaction plot with 2 continuous variables, where one of these variables is displayed as the mean and the SD on the plot.

I have been trying to use interaction_plot(), but this just returns a mess for the continuous variable. Other examples from ggplot require a regression object from lm.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of the model you are fitting?